# Using smart card for gnupg

Tags: gnupg, smartcard

I want to buy a smart card to store a gpg private key (I have never used any before).

However all options seem quite expensive. If you look for ISO 7816 in AliExpress there are much more affordable options. Same thing for Java cards.

Can I use this for gnupg? Is this relatively easy to do? I don't see anyone doing this so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you looked up the process to use a smart card for gpg? https://wiki.gnupg.org/SmartCard

Comment: or looked up " ISO 7816 gpg"? https://gnupg.org/ftp/specs/OpenPGP-smart-card-application-3.4.pdf

Comment: Thanks! But my question is more if these cards will work. Not how to set them up. For example, can I use this:
https://a.aliexpress.com/_uJY4iA ?

Comment: I assume you have a reader?

Comment: Yes, I have a smart card reader. A generic one.

Comment: @schroeder So, I am concerned about nothing and it should work ?

Comment: How many bits is your public key? Can you compare that the the storage capacity of the card you linked?

Comment: The card has 256 bits. I use and ed25519 with exactly 256 bits.

Comment: You need a card with the correct applications as well. The card you link is a **EEPROM**, providing storage, not any applications based on the description. The best advice is [probably a Yubikey](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013790259-Using-Your-YubiKey-with-OpenPGP), at around 50USD.

Comment: Oh I see, the thing is, I want something cheaper than the Yubikey. But the card satisfies the ISO 7816. That's what's bugging me, that should me complies with openpgp standard. Emphasis on "should".

Comment: Oookay, you're right buuuuut: This does it: https://www.javacardos.com/store/javacard-jc30m48cr.php. Plus the reader obviously (another $10).

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean, the Yubikey might be cheaper overall. Thanks a bunch!